# VB coding issue

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have the below query that I cannot get to run.

Can anyone advise as to the correct order of my else's and if's as I cannot see it???

my query is ....

```
select case sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")


Case"703"
currentfield = "T703"
Case"801"
currentfield = "T801"

case else 
if right(rtrim(sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")),4) = "-99C" then 
currentfield = "T020"
ElseIf
right(rtrim(sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")),3) = "EXT" then 
currentfield = "T015"
else
currentfield = "T010"

end if
end select
```

my error message is:-

[image]

all help appreciated

Comment: The error you get is *what* exactly?

Comment: What is 'sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")'

Comment: Error Compiling Script 'For Field Line Entries.PACOSTCATID' Line 121: Syntax error

Comment: Is this `sql` or `vb`?

Comment: sorry it is vb my mistake3

Comment: @user1086159 You **need** to give us your error message. Unfortunately my crystal ball is not working at the moment so I can only guess.

Comment: question updated.  sorry for the previous effort I am doing a lot of things at once.  hopefully makes more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time since I used VB but is this what you need?

```
Dim Q As String
Q = RTrim(sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage"))   

Select Case Q
Case "703"
currentfield = "T703"
Case "801"
currentfield = "T801"
Case Else
    If Right(Q, 4) = "-99C" Then
    currentfield = "T020"
    Else
        If Right(Q, 3) = "EXT" Then
        currentfield = "T015"
        Else
        currentfield = "T010"
        End If
    End If
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `ElseIf` is wrong.  the conditional statement goes on the same line.  Also I think you mean `Strings.Right`, not `right`:

```
Select Case sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")

Case"703"
    currentfield = "T703"
Case"801"
    currentfield = "T801"

Case Else
    If Strings.Right(rtrim(sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")),4) = "-99C" then 
         currentfield = "T020"
    ElseIf Strings.Right(rtrim(sourcefields("Query8111.Job Code and Stage")),3) = "EXT" then 
         currentfield = "T015"
    Else
         currentfield = "T010"    
    End If
End Select
```